# Does dark matter exist or not?

Tags: dark-matter

I've seen articles in recent days (e.g. https://physics.aps.org/articles/v14/s71) about an experiment in Spain possibly disproving the precedent finding by DAMA/LIBRA.

At the same time there are new articles about discovering a "web of dark matter" connecting the galaxies.

Have we detected dark matter yes or no?

Comment: If you're talking about direct detection then no we have not

Comment: For the bit that you mentioned about a "web of dark matter" connecting galaxies, see [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_formation#Linear_structure). Loosely speaking, dark matter played a crucial role in the formation of the large-scale structure of our universe ("webs" of galaxies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked merely provided counterevidence against one single **direct** dark matter detection done by the DAMA/LIBRA collaboration in Italy nearly 20 years ago. Nobody has ever found a reproducible result of **direct** dark matter detection. That Italian collaboration claimed to have found the expected signature of dark matter ([DAMA/LIBRA wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAMA/LIBRA)):

> This experiment has further confirmed the presence of a
> model-independent annual modulation effect in the data in 2-6 keV
> range that satisfy all the features expected for a dark matter signal
> with high statistical significance.

A large number of people working in the field direct-detection of dark matter were doubting the DAMA/LIBRA result, and now a separate experiment has finally refuted their claim (though not with total certainty just yet).

As for **indirect** detection of dark matter, there are gazillions of reproducible detections and measurements. Dark matter has irrefutably been indirectly detected, and a great deal of its properties have been measured. All of this information is detailed in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter).

The situation is, through various indirect measurements we know that dark matter exists and it has certain properties, but nobody knows what it *really is*, i.e. what it is fundamentally comprised of, so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

The evidence for dark matter is now sufficiently varied and robust that there is not really any room for doubt that it does indeed exist in roughly spherical regions centred on galaxies and in filaments between galaxies. For a summary of the evidence see other questions on this site, and wikipedia, among other places.

The evidence is from the gravitational effects, and the way these influence other things such as the way galaxies formed in the first place. But no one has yet found a particle of dark matter in their laboratory experiment on Earth, detected through some other signature such as an interaction with other particles, or a decay or something like that.